# How does linux discover and enumerate devices?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When booting (or when something is plugged in), how does linux discover that devices exist? More specifically, I'm looking to figure out what creates the ordering that is present.

My current hunch is that it walks through and probes PCI addresses, starting from either the highest or the lowest, and that orders it. For example:

```
device    address      enumerated as
UART 0   PCI 0:24.0     /dev/ttyS0
UART 1   PCI 0:24.1     /dev/ttyS1
UART 2   PCI 0:24.2     /dev/ttyS2
```

How does this hold for when a device is plugged in? Does an interrupt trigger the kernel to go deal with it? I can tell that when a new device is plugged in, it enumerates it later in the chain (in the above example, any UART would be enumerated as /dev/ttyS3 regardless of PCI address).

Edit: I should have specified - this is an **android** system that does not have udev installed - I don't even know if it has devfs (however it must since it looks like the /dev directory only contains what is needed.)

Comment: This might help you know what to look for [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/what-happens-when-a-usb-drive-is-plugged-in)

Comment: You have asked independent questions: boot time device enumeration, and hot plug events. They are utilizing slightly different mechanisms. On top of that the PCI bus has its own specifics, while other busses can do differently. At the end OS level and algorithms in the kernel. If you mark device to be probed asynchronously, the ordering might be different.

Comment: @0andriy Correct. You should move this into answer and mention device tree.

Answer (score 1):

The way in which a `hot-pluggable device` gets enumerated is different than how a `pci device` or a `platform decvice` is enumerated. A `pci device` is inherently enumerated only during boot-time (unless you do a manual pci bus rescan) and a `platform device` gets enumerated either during boot-time when the platform bus is probing for devices, or during run-time when a platform driver is loaded.
Whereas a hot-pluggable device like usb is enumerated because the usb bus is periodically polling the usb endpoints (EPs) to detect if any new usb device is connected or to service the existing usb endpoints

`probe()` is a callback function that gets called, irrespective of h/w presence, when the `bus_match_driver()` routine returns `success`. The `probe` function is called when a `device` is installed that the `driver-core` thinks it should handle; the `probe` function should perform checks on the information passed to it about the device and decide whether the driver is really appropriate for that device. A `device file` is created either manually by `mknod` or automatically by `udev` and is not directly related to `probe` function.

Answer (score 0):

Files in `/dev/` are not created by the kernel itself, but by a user-space daemon named `udev`. It names devices using a set of rules that are often located at `/lib/udev/rules.d/` and/or `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.